# same infowindow loop geocode google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, infowindow

i have a problem with infowindow. Whenever I click to view the infoWindow, it always opens the infowindow for the last location added. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

```js
for (i = 0; i < placeArray.length; i++) {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var text = placeArray[i][0];
    console.log(text);
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': placeArray[i][0]}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == 'OK') {

            test = results[0].geometry.location;
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(test.lat(), test.lng()),
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                map: map,
                icon: image,
                text : text
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker,i) {
                return function () {
                    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});
                    infowindow.setContent(marker.text);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, i));
        } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
    })
}
```

placeArray from php file

```html
/*foreach*/

echo '<script language="JavaScript">';
echo "placeArray[$count] = ['$name<br>$addressStreet $addressPost $addressCity<br><a href=\"mailto:$mail\"  class=\"link\">$mail</a><br><a href=\"tel:$phone\" class=\"link\">$phone</a>','$lang','$long']";
echo '</script>';

/*end foreach*/
```

Test array:
​

```html
   0: Array(3) [ "Serwis Narciarski i Rowerowy<br>Długa 8  87-100 Toruń<br><a href=\"mailto:\"  class=\"link\"></a><br><a href=\"tel:566210358\" class=\"link\">566210358</a>", "53.0299769", "18.5891052" ]
​
   1: Array(3) [ "PHU \"EKSPLO\" s.c. Zakład Produkcyjny i sklep firmowy<br>Mikołaja Zyblikiewicza 8 31-029 Kraków<br><a href=\"mailto:eksplo@tlen.pl\"  class=\"link\">eksplo@tlen.pl</a><br><a href=\"tel:602680588\" class=\"link\">602680588</a>", "50.0599421", "19.9431942" ]
​
   2: Array(3) [ "Sport4you Sp. z o.o.<br>Kołłątaja 27-28 50-004 Wrocław<br><a href=\"mailto:biuro@ski4you.pl\"  class=\"link\">biuro@ski4you.pl</a><br><a href=\"tel:530 120 990\" class=\"link\">530 120 990</a>", "51.102669", "17.037216" ]
​
   length: 3
​
```

Comment: because google.maps.event.addListener is always replace by next eventListener marker in loop and after whole loop is complete it has reference of last marker eventListener.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, how i can fix that - its a question now:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new object of marker each time inside the loop. Use `var` keyword to declare a new marker object each time.

As per the link given about [JavaScript Scope :](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)

> **Automatically Global**
>
> If you assign a value to a variable that has not been declared, it
>   will automatically become a GLOBAL variable.

Due to this marker holds a reference to the last added marker only. You need to create a new marker object each time inside the loop. Use `var` keyword to declare a new marker object.

```
var test = results[0].geometry.location;
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(test.lat(), test.lng()),
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            map: map,
            icon: image,
            text : text
        });
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but its still dont work. I used console.log and i I found something interesting -  "text" before geocoder.geocode in every step is different but "text" in geocoder.geocode is always the same. Maybe there is a problem ?

Comment: Yes, the geocode request is asynchronous. So the value of text changes by the time the response is received. Instead of using text while creating the marker you could use the address from the returned result as follows.

`text : results[0].formatted_address`

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest not creating multiple `Geocoder` objects like that ~ you only need one instance of the geocoder but pass whatever arguments to it in the loop.

```
if( placeArray.length > 0 ){

    /*
        Where is `image` defined?
    */


    const geocallback=function(results,status,text,image){
        if( status=='OK' ){
            let pos = results[0].geometry.location;
            let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(pos),
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                map: map,
                icon: image,
                text : text
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click', function(event){
                let infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                    infowindow.setContent( this.text );
                    infowindow.open( this.position );
            }.bind( marker ) );

        } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
    };

    let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    for( i = 0; i < placeArray.length; i++ ) {
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': placeArray[i][0] }, function(results,status){
            geocallback.call( this, results, status, placeArray[i][0], image );
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but new problem show up : "TypeError: placeArray[i] is undefined, can't access property 0 of it".

Comment: can you add `placeArray` to the question?

Comment: Yes, i just added.

Comment: Why use the Geocoder service when the source data has the latitude and longitude so the marker can be placed on the map with no need to use the geocoding service??

Comment: because i have to delete latitiude and longitude from source data